# Why serverReadyAction configuration open the 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost in browser?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have followed the [Automatically open a URI when debugging a server program](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_automatically-open-a-uri-when-debugging-a-server-program) document to create a configuration to debug my program. I have added the `serverReadyAction` feature to open the URL in my browser. The `uriFormat` is set to `"http://localhost:%s"`. However, VS Code opens `http://127.0.0.1:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000` in my browser. How can I fix this?

I am using WSL (Ubuntu 22.04).

Here is my `.vscode/launch.json` configuration:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "ts-node",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [
        "${file}"
      ],
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "listening on.* (https?://\\S+|[0-9]+)",
        "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
        "action": "openExternally"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And my `app.js` file:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

Comment: localhost is normally `http://127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `hosts` file of windows

```bash
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Remove the comment symbol `#` for the `127.0.0.1 localhost` DNS record.

`hosts`:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

If VS Code has already connected to WSL, choose `Remote: Close Remote Connection` from the command palette. Then reconnect to WSL.

Debug program again, then VS Code will open `http://localhost:3000` in the browser.